# Data insertion failed with salesforce inspector

Tags: api, opportunity, record-type, data, insert

I don't understand why I get this error **INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: 0121t0000001qxAAAQ [RecordTypeId]**
[image]

I want to insert field numbers in a 'history' object that links these numbers to the corresponding opportunities.
I think I may have put the wrong API name for the field?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer, in fact it was the wrong object's ID ! So I took the 'history' object ID and it's fine now.

Answer (score 4):

This error means that your user does not have access to the record type you have specified. With Id 0121t0000001qxAAAQ.

You can either grant access to this in the user's [Profile](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_profiles_record_types.htm&type=5) or via a [Permission Set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/perm_sets_record_types_assign.htm).

For more information, see [How Is Record Type Access Specified?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/permissions_record_type_access.htm)